# Using existing playlists on Google Play music

Tags: music, music-player, google-play-music

I have a Nexus S, and I sync my music between iTunes and my phone using iSyncr, which basically just dumps the music files and playlist files into a folder within my phone's USB storage. I'm using iSyncr instead of Google Play to get music to my phone, because I want a true *sync*, which, in my understanding, Google Play's uploaded doesn't currently do with iTunes.

Until recently, Google Play music would read both the music files and playlists, but with the most recent update it no longer sees the playlists.

Anyone have any idea how I might go about fixing this ("fixing" meaning getting my *synced* playlists from iTunes to show up in Google Play music on my phone)?